# How can I get all issues from a specific unreleased version via jira rest api

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I am not administrator of my project.I want to get list of all JIRAS from specific unreleased version so that I can close them after production release.How can I get such jira list via jira rest API??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this JQL:

```
project = PROJECTKEY and fixVersion = 3.5.2 AND resolution is EMPTY
```

And send it with the `GET` HTTP method to the `api/2/search` endpoint using the `jql` queryparam

Full example:

```
GET https://yourjiraserver.com/api/2/search?jql=project%20%3D%20PROJECTKEY%20and%20fixVersion%20%3D%203.5.2%20AND%20resolution%20is%20EMPTY
```

Comment: Thanks for answer!!